# Mot français féminin qui termine par -age?

Tags: genre, suffixes

Y a-t-il un mot (d'origine française) qui termine par *-age*, mais qui est féminin ?

La motivation de cette question est le fait que tous les mots français qui terminent par *-age* et qui sont utilisés comme mots d'emprunt en allemand sont traités comme féminins, et je me demande s'il existe une exception en français qui a servi comme modèle erroné.

Comment: Je ne comprend pas la question, veux-tu dire un mot qui soit masculin ? Sinon, la question n'a pas vraiment de sens...

Comment: @Raphink: Je ne comprends pas ton commentaire. Pourquoi devrait-je demander des mots masculins? Ils le sont tous normalement, le garage, le massage, le vernissage, ... et tous ces mots existent comme mots feminins en allemand (die Garage, die Massage, die Vernissage, ...)

Comment: Ah, the comprend maintenant.

Comment: Dans le même esprit, notez que le mot "cation" se termine par "-tion" mais qu'il est masculin...

Comment: @BrennanVincent le cas de *cation* est un peu spécial, n'étant pas une substantivation avec suffice *-tion* mais plutot une construction dont la racine est *ion*. Le *t* précédent appartient au préfixe *cat-* (et même *cath-* avant cela) évoquant la *cathode* (vers laquelle se dirigent les cations).

Comment: Tous ces emprunts sont des noms d'action déverbaux comme *vernissage* ou bien aussi des collectifs de noms comme *feuillage* ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Une liste de ces mots se trouvent sur le [Wiktionaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-age)

> Les mots se finissant en -age sont habituellement masculins. Les exceptions sont cage, énallage, hypallage, image, nage, page, plage, rage, saxifrage (qui ne dérivent pas du suffixe).

Liste à laquelle il faut ajouter « ambage », utilisé en général au pluriel dans l'expression « sans ambages ».

Comment: Bien vu. On en a trouvé 5 sur 9, c'est pas si mal ;-)

Comment: il manque une mage

Comment: @smug tu confonds probablement avec l'adjectif.

Comment: non, une mage, le nom, l'emploi féminin est certainement rare mais il existe

Comment: @smug [à lire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89pic%C3%A8ne#Confusion_entre_emploi_g.C3.A9n.C3.A9rique_et_.C3.A9pic.C3.A8ne) > **un** mage.

Comment: @Kn merci pour la référence, mais quand je dit qu'une mage noire de niveau cent vient de te jeter un sort, c'est bien d'une mage qu'il s'agit... et pas d'une panthère rose.

Comment: @smug tu n'as qu'à poser la question tu verras bien ^^

Comment: admettons que je n'ai cure des protestations de l'Académie française, quelque vigoureuses qu'elles soient, je m'obstinerai à dire une mage, comme on dit une ministre, ou une juge.

Comment: euh oui c'est pas parce que tu dis quelque chose que c'est juste!

Comment: *Une hypallage* ? OO Nom de dieu merci les listes quand même...

Comment: assurance-chômage  ( http://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/divers/ch%C3%B4mage/33620#771203 , http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/assurance-ch%C3%B4mage )

Answer (score 10):

Le suffixe *-age* est toujours masculin. C'est un suffixe très productif, il n'est donc pas surprenant que la grande majorité des mots en -age soient obtenus par cette formation. Je renvoie à l'[article -age du Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-age) pour une analyse très détaillée de l'histoire et des valeurs possibles de ce suffixe.

Il y a quelques rares mots qui se trouvent se terminer par les lettres `age` sans qu'il ne s'agissent d'un suffixe autonome. Dans ce cas, le mot peut être indifféremment masculin ou féminin, il n'y a pas de règle. Une image, une page, une rage, un voyage, …

Comment: Il me semble qu'il existe deux suffixes -age, tous les deux donnant des noms masculins. L'un forme des noms d'action à partir de verbes laver => lavage, l'un donne des collectifs feuille => feuillage.