# Féminin du mot « mage »

Tags: genre, noms, genre-biologique

Quand je fais des recherches sur le mot « mage » (désignant un utilisateur de magie), toutes les documentations désignent que ce mot est exclusivement masculin. Si j'utilise ce mot pour désigner un personnage féminin, est-ce que je peux l'accorder au féminin, ou dois-je utiliser un autre mot ? J'aimerais éviter d'utiliser les mots « magicienne » et « sorcière ».

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/156/mot-francais-feminin-qui-termine-par-age/168#168

Comment: Il y a sans doute quelque chose qui m'échappe, mais étymologie mise-à-part, le mot "mage" en français moderne, n'a pas grand chose à voir avec un "utilisateur de magie". Comme le rappelle @Evpok, il s'agit avant tout d'un terme désignant une *ethnie* (à la réputation mystérieuse, d'où l'association avec la magie), dont l'utilisation moderne est essentiellement cantonnée aux discussions bibliques (les rois Mages, souvent traduits par "wise men" en anglais). Le mot que tu décris ci-dessus est "magicien" ou "magicienne", pas "mage"...

Comment: Hormis les rois Mages, la seule autre utilisation qui me vient à l'esprit c'est la réaction du servant d'Amonbofis quand les g..g..gaulois sortent indemnes de la pyramide :)

Comment: en français, wiktionary nous donne: Astrologue, devin, spécialiste des sciences occultes et de la prédiction de l’avenir. Prêtre de la religion de Zoroastre, chez les Perses et les Mèdes.

Comment: Selon la tradition, les rois mages sont précisément des prêtres zoroastriens.

Comment: Il parle de l'utilisation du terme en tant que [classe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magicien_(classe_de_personnage)) de personnage dans les jeux de rôles.

Comment: -1 pour n'avoir trouvé que de la mauvaise documentation : *mage* est bien féminin (souvent). D'ailleurs, quand j'ai besoin de magie du feu, je monte une mage.

Answer (score 8):

Le fait que les dictionnaires le listent comme un mot masculin plutôt qu'épicène ne veut pas forcéement dire qu'on ne peut pas l'utiliser pour une femme. *Mage* convient donc très bien pour une femme. Un synonyme plus évidemment épicène serait [*thaumaturge*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/thaumaturge), qui signifie « qui fait des miracles ».

En fait si on en reste au sens historique, les [mages](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Mage) étant les membres d'une ethnie<sup>1</sup>, il est probable qu'il y ait eu des femmes mages, *une mage* ne me paraît donc vraiment pas impossible, mais ceci n'a pas vraiment de rapport.

Évidemment, tout ceci ne signifie pas qu'on ne pourrait pas *inventer* une alternative comme par exemple *magesse*.

—
<sub>1. Et, plus tard, les prêtres, disciples, voire fidèles de Zarathustra. je ne suis pas suffisament familier avec l'[Avesta](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Avesta) pour me risquer à affirmer que ceux-ci pouvaient être des femmes, mais [wikipedia:en](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Zoroastrianism#Other_characteristics) évoque « the Zoroastrian tenets of gender equality », donc, encore une fois *une mage* ne me semble pas insensé.</sub>

Comment: « Morgane, le mage diabolique » ? Non… Je demande des preuves !

Comment: Une sentinelle, un sentineau? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Si tu l'utilises dans un contexte fantastique ou « heroic-fantasy », je pense que tu peux te permettre toutes les variations que tu veux.

Il y a des recherches à faire mais je pense qu'en anglais, *Mage* a été inventé récemment pour la littérature fantastique, en se basant sur le nom des astronomes-astrologues de l'ancienne perse (*Magos*, *Mage*, …).

En français, on a donc traduit *Mage* par *Mage*.

Donc ce n'est pour moi que dans un contexte fantastique qu'on emploi *mage* avec un sens de « personne qui fait de la magie, boules de feu etc… ».

A partir de là, vu comment sont les règles de féminisation des titres en français moderne (pas très claires), tu peux choisir *une mage* ou *un mage*. Ou autres de ton choix bien sûr, l'avantage de la fantaisie c'est aussi la créativité.

Comment: Une variation qui sonne bien à mes oreilles est magesse, sur le modèle de prêtresse et qui conserve la proximité avec sagesse.

Comment: et une "magestueuse"?

Answer (score 3):

Je sais que les dictionnaires donnent simplement le mot comme un nom masculin, mais je l'ai déjà vu utilisé au féminin dans des romans sans que ça me choque (alors que l'utilisation comme quasi-synonyme de *magicien*, me choque; pour moi un *mage* est plus passif — communication avec les esprits, divination, ... —, mais l'usage n'est pas d'accord avec moi).

Comment: c'est le français vu au travers de l'heroic-fantasy?

Comment: En dehors de ça et des contes de Noël, le mot mage est plutôt rare.  Et dans les contes de Noël, il ne s'applique pas à des personnages féminins.

Comment: Je ne différencie pas *mage* et *magicien*, mais ça dépend vraiment énormément du contexte (cf le [commentaire de Knu](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/feminin-du-mot-mage?rq=1#comment2151_1090)). +1 pour *mage* comme féminin.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais surtout que « mage » ne se dit que très rarement au féminin (désolé, Un francophone !).

Si je regarde les résultats d'une [recherche dans Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22une%20mage%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr), ils sont peu nombreux et la plupart d'entre eux sont en fait des erreurs de reconnaissance de caractères (le plus souvent, « une image » dont le *i* a été ignoré).

Quelques exceptions, pour la fine bouche :

> L'Italie entière détesterait Numa, si Numa devenait l'époux d'une Mage (Florian, *Numa Pompilius, second roi de Rome*, 1786)
>
> Si un Musulman épouse une femme qu'il ne lui est pas permis d'épouser, une esclave juive ou chrétienne ou bien encore une Mage libre par exemple, le mariage n'est pas valide (*Archives marocaines*, 1909)
>
> une mage (n. f.) : plateau pour pommes à cidre (*Dictionnaires des homonymes de la langue française*)

Comment: C'est peut-être vrai, et d'autant plus malheureux.

Answer (score -1):

Personnellement, si c'est par exemple pour un jeu ou un récit de Heroic Fantasy, j'utiliserais le mot *prêtresse*. Je ne pense pas que dans l'imaginaire du lecteur (ou du joueur) cela soit pris pour le féminin de *prêtre* dans le sens catholique, car, eh bien, ça n'existe pas. *Prêtresse* fait beaucoup plus penser à la magie qu'à la foi.

Comment: J'ai bien peur que *prêtresse* n'ait déjà été détourné à d'autres fins (guérisseuse, essentiellement, sans le côté « plantes »), et que ça ne soit compris comme ça par la plupart de ceux qui sont familiers avec cet univers.